# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

another "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in " question but the answers given did not help resolve my problem!

I am trying to write the information received via post from a form and use php to write it to mysql database.

The error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/.../myform.php on line 17
```

my php code:

```
<?PHP

session_start();


require("DBconnect.php");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
// data sent from contactForm


// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Final (user_name, first_name, last_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $user_name, $first_name, $last_name);

// set parameters from POST request and execute
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$stmt->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

my DBconnect.php contains the following:

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pasword', 'dbname');
?>
```

Comment: `$conn` is not defined...

Comment: As @chris85 says, `$conn` is not defined. Pretty sure you meant `$mysqli->prepare(...);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call `prepare()` on a wrong object. It's not `$conn`, but `$mysqli`.

Comment: That's what I was going to say ha. People really should look a little more into their problem before posting on here.